# Why is there a factor of $2$ in the isomorphism $\operatorname{Lie}(S^3)\cong\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, spheres

As a training problem I tried to explicitly compute the isomorphism between the Lie algebra of $S^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the cross product. I used the following notations: Let $U=\{x=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)\in S^3)\ |\ x_0>0\}$ and let $\varphi:U\to \mathbb{R}^3,\ x\mapsto (x_1,x_2,x_3)$. After a fairly long calculation, I arrived at the following: if we identify $\operatorname{Lie}(S^3)$ with $T_{e}S^3$ in the usual way, then we have
$$
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi_i}|_e,\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi_{i+1}}|_e\right]=2\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi_{i+2}}|_e
$$
where $\varphi=(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3)$ and the indices are taken modulo 3. What surprises me about this is the presence of the factor of $2$, which makes it so that the searched isomorphism $\operatorname{Lie}(S^3)\cong\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by
$$
f:\operatorname{Lie}(S^3)\cong\mathbb{R}^3\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi_1}|_e\mapsto (2,0,0),\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi_2}|_e\mapsto (0,2,0),\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi_3}|_e\mapsto (0,0,2),
$$
but intuitively I would have thought that in the isomorphism there is no such factor of $2$. Have I just done an error somewhere in my calculations? Or is it indeed true that by some coincidence there is a factor of $2$ in the isomorphism?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The Lie algebra of $S^3$ is $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, and the Lie algebra for $\Bbb R^3$ with the cross product is $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$. And of course there is a Lie algebra isomorphism $f\colon \mathfrak{su}(2)\rightarrow \mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$ with $f(\sigma_i/2)=e_i$, where $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices - see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/lie-group-homomorphism-su2-to-so3).